# Margin the second view in Framelayout

Tags: android, android-framelayout

How to margin the second view in framelayout ?

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon_guide"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" 
                android:id="@+id/guide"
                />
        </FrameLayout>
```

I set layoutParams margins but i don't get a bottom and right margin.

```
final FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mIconGuide.getLayoutParams();
params.bottomMargin= 50;
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
mIconGuide.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: You can't use android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"?

Comment: it is in px , and why not?

Comment: I mean I was asking if you can use it or not.

Comment: well , i set params.topMargin and it work
and i want to do that dynamically